# removing href using phpquery problem

Tags: php, css

Hi I need to remove the link of a screen scrap site here is the output source.

```
<div class="FourDayForecastContainerInner">
<span class="day">Friday</span>
    <a href="forecastPublicExtended.asp#Period4" target="_blank">
        <img src="./images/wimages/b_rain.gif" class="thumbnail">
    </a>
    <span class="hi">
        <span style="width:24px;">Hi</span> 
        19 / 66
    </span>
    <span class="lo">
    <span style="width:24px;">Lo</span> 
        16 / 60
    </span>

    <span class="description">
    Sunny Breaks,  showers
    </span>
</div>

<div class="FourDayForecastContainerInner">
    <span class="day">Saturday</span>
```

and here is my code Im using phpquery

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML( $e );  
$containers = pq('.FourDayForecastContainerInner', $doc); 
foreach( $containers as $container ) {
  $div = pq('span', $container);
  $img = pq('img', $container);
  $div->eq(0)
      ->removeAttr('style')
      ->addClass('day')
      ->html( 
        pq( 'u', $div->eq(0) )
        ->html() 
      );

  $img->eq(0)
      ->removeAttr('style')
      ->removeAttr('height')
      ->removeAttr('width')
      ->removeAttr('alt')
      ->addClass('thumbnail')
      ->html( pq( 'img', $img->eq(0)) );   

  $div->eq(1)
      ->removeAttr('style')
      ->addClass('hi');  

  $div->eq(3)
      ->removeAttr('style')
      ->addClass('lo'); 

  $div->eq(5)
      ->removeAttr('style')
      ->addClass('description');   
} 
print $doc;
```

I have manage to remove all attributes styles height width etc. but i can't seem to remove the a href
thank you so much for your help

Comment: Please format your code; indent every line by four spaces to have it as a block code. (See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with your sample code and it works. This is the output

```
<div class='FourDayForecastContainerInner'>

                        <span class='day'>Friday</span>

                            <img src='./images/wimages/b_rain.gif' class='thumbnail'>
                        <span class='hi'>
                            <span style='width:24px;'>Hi</span>
                            19 / 66
                        </span>
                        <span class='lo'>

                            <span style='width:24px;'>Lo</span>
                            16 / 60
                        </span>

                        <span class='description'>
                            Sunny Breaks,  showers
                  </span>


              </div>

                <div class='FourDayForecastContainerInner'>

                        <span class='day'>Saturday</span><div class='FourDayForecastContainerInner'>

                        <span class='day'>Friday</span>

                            <img src='./images/wimages/b_rain.gif' class='thumbnail'>
                        <span class='hi'>
                            <span style='width:24px;'>Hi</span>

                            19 / 66
                        </span>
                        <span class='lo'>
                            <span style='width:24px;'>Lo</span>
                            16 / 60
                        </span>

                        <span class='description'>
                            Sunny Breaks,  showers
                  </span>


              </div>

                <div class='FourDayForecastContainerInner'>

                        <span class='day'>Saturday</span>
```

The way you are doing is too long and tiresome. Use regular expressions to replace the link.

Comment: Can I view your code so I can compare and see what I'm doing wrong, I am not that familliar with php what do you mean by regular expressions may be if you can show me how you code it I would learn how do regular expressions thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$html  = 'Your HTMl CODE HERE';

$exp = "~<a.*>~isU";
$html = preg_replace($exp,"", $html);
$exp = "~</a>~isU";
$html = preg_replace($exp,"", $html);

echo $html
```

this will totally remove the link

Comment: it doesn't seem to work can you check http://j2sdesign.com/rgw/article/20101222/NEWS01/712229951/0/example/ca-test.txt and view source you can see the php code since i added a comment tag thank you for your help I was able to remove the link in the div but I am having problems with the span. the site Im scraping is really hard to screen scrap beacuse of its coding

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code do what you want ? (when added at the end of 'for' loop)

```
$imghtml = pq('a', $container)->html();
pq($container)->prepend($imghtml);
pq('a', $container)->remove();
```

Note : phpquery doesn't seem to support jquery detach()

Comment: Here is the result I get with this code : <div class="FourDayForecastContainerInner">
        <img src="./images/wimages/b_rain.gif" class="thumbnail">
<span class="day"></span>
    
    <span class="hi">
        <span style="width:24px;">Hi</span> 
        19 / 66
    </span>
    <span class="lo">
    <span style="width:24px;">Lo</span> 
        16 / 60
    </span>

    <span class="description">
    Sunny Breaks,  showers
    </span>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same question and I wanted to share my solution.  My goal was to remove all tags from the title portion of some SoundCloud embed code.  The HTML looked like this:

```
<object height="81" width="100%"> 
... a bunch of embed code ...  
</object>  
<span>
  <a href="http://soundcloud.com/minimal/mike-ink-silver">Mike Ink _ Silver</a> 
  by 
  <a href="http://soundcloud.com/minimal">MINIMAL</a>
</span>
```

At the end of the HTML above, you can see that the title has not only one but *two* links around it.  My goal was to strip those out.

Assuming that HTML is assigned to the PHP variable $text, here's how I did it:

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($text);
$soundcloud_title = strip_tags((string) $doc->find('span'));
print($soundcloud_title);

// outputs: Mike Ink _ Silver by MINIMAL
```

I know that this doesn't directly answer the question.  In fact, I'm using strip_tags to remove the links instead of using phpquery, but I hoped it might help other coders who are looking for the same answers I was.

Happy coding!